# Change terminal background from bash script in platform, desktop environment independent way?

Tags: terminal

How can I change terminal background color in a way that utilizes ONLY the terminal protocol and does not depend on ANY configuration (as in "profiles") stored in a specific terminal program or the environment in which it is running?

I want to be able to write a script that will reliably change the terminal background color for whoever logs into the machine using a terminal and executes the script.

A quick and authoritative answer to the effect of "this is impossible" will be as appreciated as a solution. Such an answer will however only be accepted from an expert who knows terminal protocols exhaustively and can attest the absence of such a feature.

Comment: impossible. what works for mate-terminal may or may not work for konsole and what works there may or may not work with gnome-terminal and none of it will work with a real TTY (alt+f1, etc)

Comment: Don't terminal programs set environment variables to identify themselves? I only require the solution not to depend on configuration stored clientside. I do not require the solution to be a one-liner. I do not require the solution to abstain from detecting the terminal type and using whatever works for that terminal type. Lastly, real TTY doesn't need to be supported.

Comment: Do you want the script to write text on black background, or the whole screen (and scrollback buffer?) of the terminal emulator to turn black? With or without affecting what's already displayed on that screen? What if the current foreground color is also black?

Comment: Whole screen yes, scrollback buffer no. Not necessarily black, more like FIERY RED to serve as a warning. Also to be clear, I want the script to **set** red background permanently, not just echo something on red background.

Comment: `xtermcontrol --bg Firebrick` (or `printf '\33]11;Firebrick\7`) would work on `xterm`-compatible terminals but would also change the scrollback buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible. I'm not an expert who knows terminal protocols exhaustively, but I am aware of the existence of terminals that have no way to change the background color. This is the case, for example, on dumb terminals such as provided by [expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) or by `M-x shell` in Emacs. This is also the case of most hardware terminals, but few people use those nowadays.

Most terminal emulators do have a way to change the background color. Terminal emulators by and large copy xterm for the interface between the application and the terminal, so when you want a feature like this, try the xterm way and expect it to work on some but not all terminal emulators. Look up the [xterm control sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) and see if one fits what you want.

For changing the background color of the whole terminal, there's [`OSC 11; color BEL`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Operating-System-Commands), i.e.

```
printf '\e]11;%s\a' "$color"
```

This works in xterm, urxvt, gnome-terminal, konsole and lxterm, but not in rxvt, xfce4-terminal, terminator or Emacs `M-x term`. The background color change survives a terminal reset. You can also change the foreground color by replacing `11;` with `10;`.

That's the default background color, of course. On any terminal that supports this escape sequence, and most other terminals that support colors in any way, you can switch the background color for subsequently displayed text with `\e[41m` (for red).

If the escape sequence isn't supported in a terminal, then you have no way to find out. You can try finding an escape sequence that queries the terminal and that's supported in the same set of terminals, but usually there's no such sequence.

Switching to reverse video with `\e[?5h` probably works on most terminals but this doesn't survive a terminal reset. You could do that and then set the foreground color, this way there would be a visual effect on most terminals.

Comment: Thank you! I went the xterm way because it turns out that all the relevant people (for whom it should work) happen to use xterm-compatible emulators. I also did find that nice `tput` utility that does present a unified-ish interface to various terminal capabilities.